# Why $\dot{a}\ddot{a}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\dot{a}^{2}\right)$

Tags: calculus

can someone explain me why

$\dot{a}\ddot{a}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\dot{a}^{2}\right)$

Many thanks

Comment: The [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Product Rule. The derivative of $\dot{a}\dot{a}$ with respect to $t$ is $\dot{a}\ddot{a}+\dot{a}\ddot{a}$, which is
$2\dot{a}\ddot{a}$.

Comment: Now I see, my problem was thatI tried to do something with LHS, whereas I should just use product rule on RHS... thanks

Answer (score 1):

or use the chain rule. $\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\big((\dot a)^2\big)=\frac{d}{dt}f(\dot a(t))$, where $f(x)=x^2$. So you first take the derivative w.r.t $f$ evaluated at $\dot a$ and then you take the time derivative of the argument of $f$, which is $\ddot a$.

Comment: My problem was starting with LHS whereas I should start with RHS... silly me, thanks anyway!